# Does R have a medical corpus?

Tags: r

I have received a text containing medical terms, and I want to use text mining on it to get a word count. I would like to know if R has a medical corpus that I can use so that I can compare my text document to the medical corpus.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about asking for an R text corpus.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of one, but importing a textual dataset into R is trivial, once you understand the corpus' layout. I'm biased, but the textual data set used in my biomedical informatics dissertation might be a good place to start. My answer on [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/88926/dataset-and-papers-for-baseline/88933#88933) provides the additional details you'll need.